# C++ - Unresolved external symbols

Tags: c++, class, linker, external-dependencies

Simply put:

foo.h:

```
#include "bar.h"
class foo {
private:
    bar it;
    void DoIt();
}
```

bar.h:

```
class bar {
public:
    void Test();
}
```

foo.cpp:

```
void foo::DoIt() {
    it.Test();
}
```

This will result in a:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol

Why?

Comment: Closed as user posted answer to own question.

Answer (score 2):

You have not written the code for `bar::Test()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb! I did define Test() in the class definition but did not actually have an existing Test() function :(

Sorry.